# OpenCV with Python - Placing an image of a hat over the head of a webcam feed

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I am trying to place a png image of a hat over the head of a webcam feed. I am trying to detect a face and place the image above it. This is my code so far -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

imghat = cv2.imread('hat.png', -1)

print imghat is None

imghatGray = cv2.cvtColor(imghat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imghatGray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)

# Convert hat image to BGR
# and save the original image size (used later when re-sizing the image)
imghat = imghat[:,:,0:3]
origHatHeight, origHatWidth = imghat.shape[:2]

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5, flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print "x : %d , y : %d, w: %d, h: %d " %(x,y,w,h)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x-15,y-h), (x+w+15, y), (255,255,0), 2)

        print w
        print h
        hatWidth = w
        hatHeight = hatWidth * origHatHeight / origHatWidth

        roi_gray = gray[y-hatHeight:y, x-15:x+w+15]
        roi_color = frame[y-hatHeight:y, x-15:x+w+15]

        # Center the hat
        x1 = x - 15
        y1 = y - h
        x2 = x + w +15
        y2 = y

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1,y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 2)

        # Check for clipping
        if x1 < 0:
            x1 = 0
        if y1 < 0:
            y1 = 0
        if x2 > w:
            x2 = w
        if y2 > h:
            y2 = h

        # Re-calculate the width and height of the hat image
        hatWidth = x2 - x1
        hatHeight = y2 - y1

        # Re-size the original image and the masks to the hat sizes
        # calcualted above
        hat = cv2.resize(imghat, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # take ROI for hat from background equal to size of hat image
        roi = roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2]

        # roi_bg contains the original image only where the hat is not
        # in the region that is the size of the hat.
        roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

        # roi_fg contains the image of the hat only where the hat is
        roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(hat,hat,mask = mask)

        # join the roi_bg and roi_fg
        dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)

        # place the joined image, saved to dst back over the original image
        roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2] = dst

        break


    # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this error - **OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize** everytime I run it. The webcam start and closes abruptly. The error is somewhere in -

```
            hat = cv2.resize(imghat, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (hatWidth,hatHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

The values of hatWidth and hatHeight are negative. But I cannot find an error in the assignment of the coordinates. Is it because of the ROI in the program?

Comment: Hey, looks like it's been a while since this post. Wanted to follow up - did you ever get this working? Does it still seem like a reasonable approach 5 years later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code `Center the hat` you have:

```
    x1 = x - 15
    x2 = x + w +15
```

where x1 and x2 seem to be the horizontal bounds of the hat.

Then, a few lines later, *without x1 and x2 changing values* you have

```
    # Check for clipping
    if x1 < 0:
        x1 = 0
    if x2 > w:
        x2 = w
```

This code will *always* modify x2 since x2 is by definition greater than w, in facts it's `x + w + 15`. This is probably not what you intended.

A few lines further you set hatWidth to

```
hatWidth = x2 - x1
```

At this point, x2 is always `w` due to the above 'clipping' code

So, if x2 is less than x1 this will make hatWidth negative which causes the  problem you're seeing in `cv2.resize( ... )`.

When will x2 be less than x1? Well, x2 is w and x1 is `x - 15` so whenever w < (x - 15) which is w + 15 < x i.e. whenever the position of the detected face is further right than the width of the face plus 15; this seems like something which could happen quite regularly and should't actually be an issue.

I suspect your clipping code should be checking for x2 being greater than the *image* width, not the face width.

You have a similar problem with clipping y2

Comment: I had to comment out the equations below the clipping part to print. The values are  - x1: 228 , y1 : 0, x2: 274, y2: 166 
x : 255 , y : 177, w: 255, h: 255

Comment: You say that `The values of hatWidth and hatHeight are negative` Where are you printing these to establish that they are negative ?

Comment: I tried printing out the values after the recalculating lines (hatWidth = x2- x1 and hatHeight = y2 -y1), the hatWidth becomes negative after a few iterations. hatWidth: -29, hatHeight: 195

Comment: I set the clipping limit to 640 and 360, and the rectangle is above the head. Thank you. I've still got issues with the ROI regions after resizing. I'll post another question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. The solution is found by plotting the co ordinates values. One such point was lying outside the dimensions of the image. So was getting error. I fixed it later and set bounding conditions so that the ROI dimensions dont exceed the image dimensions. Thanks anyway.